# Writing python's Dictionary in excel spreadsheets within an excel file

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dictionary

I have a dictionary say Dict which have several keys like 1234,23343,35433 and every key corresponds to values of type list . Within each values we can data frames or class of Nonetype.

I would like to write the whole dictionary in a single excel file having several spreadsheets in which the tab of every spreadsheet is nothing but the keys in dict and all the values that specific have should be appended in that spreadsheet. 
i.e 1234 key might have values containing three dataframes in it. So the excel spreadsheet tab name will be 1234 and it should have data from all the three dataframes.

Comment: So what exactly are you having trouble with? Can you show us what you've tried so far?

Comment: also showing us a sample of your data is going to be helpful to others

Answer (score 0):

What I am trying to achieve:
a. I want to write the dictionary in single excel file such that keys corresponds to spreadsheet name and values should be written inside that specific spreadsheet.
b. If I go by my logic then I am stuck up in storing every dataframe that gets generated in every iteration into the spreadsheet.

What I have tried and achieved so far:
I could able to create spreadsheet tabs from dictionary keys but I am still struggling with writing the values of dictionary inside dataframes.

My code snippet:

```
final_dataframe=pd.DataFrame(Master_dict)
    # I converted the dictionary into dataframe 
    import xlsxwriter
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter('file.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
    workbook = writer.book
    web_ClassID=df_stag["Web-Class ID"].unique()
    for data_id, df in df_stag.groupby('specific_col'): 
      for workbook_Id in web_ClassID:
        if workbook_Id == data_id:
            worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet(workbook_Id)
            for index, col in enumerate(df):
               df.to_excel(writer, index=False )
               writer.save()
    workbook.close()
```

Note: with the above snippet only first dataframe is written in excel file with one spreadsheet. It is not storing further dataframes in successive speadsheets.
I hope this might be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried another workaround to this question.
I converted the dictionary into dataframe and then created an excel file containing keys as tabs and copied the content inside excel spreadsheets with respect to keys.

```
df=pd.dataframe(dict)
df.to_excel(writer,sheet_name=workbook_Id)
workbook.close()
```

But I want to convert dictionary to a single excel file containing tabs same as the keys of dictionary and values copied inside each tabs of excel.